# On a quest for the super ultimate facebook share link

Tags: facebook

Facebook offers two simple methods for pre-poulating someones status for posting.

1) For sharing a LINK: http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://350.org

2) For sharing a message: http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?&message=350.org rocks!

My question: is it possible to combine these. So if someone clicks your pre-populated link, they get both an attached LINK and a personalized message to go with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook *moved* to [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and realized it by introducing the [Like Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like). They removed the share documentation for a reason!

For you to use the Like plugin.